# Cant resolve an Issue in Data binding in Android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, visual-studio, kotlin, data-binding

I am trying to bind a data object to my layout using data binding. but I get an error of type mismatch. and I don't understand the reason as I am new to data binding.
my code is very simple, and hope someone can guide me to understand my mistake here.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private var myName : MyName = MyName("Ahmed Rabee")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    binding.myName.text = myName.name
  }
```

The data class

```
data class MyName(var name: String = "" , var nickName: String = "")
```

the layout

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="myName"
            type="com.example.aboutme.MyName" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_name"
        style="@style/name_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@{myName.name}"
         />
```

and this is the error I am getting, and I can't understand why at all it says type mismatch.

I tried to switch it to this snippet of code, yet it doesn't work. as it doesn't show any data on the layout.

```
    binding.myName.text = myName.name
```

Hope someone can guide me in this. where is my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Initialize your layout myName variable with MyName object inside onCreate(). Please try below changes in your code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
 private var myName : MyName = MyName("Ahmed Rabee")

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

 binding.myName = myName
 }
}
```